# Sort elements in two lines using CSS

Tags: html, css, magento

I'm customizing Magento 1.9 payment method selector. It renders a dl list where the dt element has the method name and the dd element has the method information. I would like to render all dt elements side by side on the first line and the dd methods at the second line. I tried making the dl flex and using order on dt and dd elements, without success.

```
<dl id="checkout-payment-method">
   <dt id="dt_method_1"></dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_1"></dd>
   <dt id="dt_method_2"></dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_2"></dd>
   <dt id="dt_method_3"></dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_3"></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: `dt` and `dd` are in order for specific semantic reasons per definition & description. Why not just change the output structure all together to suit your purposes instead and maybe at least incorporate something like `aria-labelledby` attributes for minimal equivalent?

Comment: Hi @ChrisW. dt/dd is generated by the backoffice app on this sequence, to change it I must change Magento's core, and I don't intend to do it due our update management policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I wouldn't recommend negating the explicit semantic hierarchy you do have some hacky options such as;

```css
#checkout-payment-method {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#checkout-payment-method dt, #checkout-payment-method dd {  
  margin: 0;
  width: 33%;
}

#checkout-payment-method dt {
  border: red 1px solid;
  order: 1
}

#checkout-payment-method dd {
  border: green 1px solid;
  order: 2
}
```

```html
<dl id="checkout-payment-method">
   <dt id="dt_method_1">dt1</dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_1">dd1</dd>
   <dt id="dt_method_2">dt2</dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_2">dd2</dd>
   <dt id="dt_method_3">dt3</dt>
   <dd id="dd_method_3">dd3</dd>
</dl>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!